# Using Core Audio, is it possible to change desktop's audio output device?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-core-audio

On WPF C#, I am trying to set up a button that toggles between two audio output devices - headset and earphone. Are there methods to do so?

For reference, I downloaded Core Audio Wrapper from https://whenimbored.xfx.net/2011/01/core-audio-for-net/

All other features of the button is complete. It can detect audio devices, and when the botton is pressed, the variable change. But I have no clue how to set that variable to be the audio output devide of the desktop.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.